# vue with vuex computed property not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using vuex and socket.io for state.Nodes.nodes update. I'm updating single​ node (index 4) and when I'm logging using setInterval the output_state and computed properties that is exactly the same (node 4 output_state) - they differ after mutation!

```
computed: {
  tmpStatus () {
    if (this.$store.state.Nodes.nodes.length !== 0) {
      return this.$store.state.Nodes.nodes[4].output_state
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
},
created () {
  this.debugInterval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Devicesstate', this.$store.state.Nodes.nodes[4].output_state, this.tmpStatus)
  }, 2000)
},
```

The mutation is done that way:

```
let nodeFound = state.nodes.filter(item => item.node_id === node.node_id)[0]
let nodeIndex = state.nodes.indexOf(nodeFound)
state.nodes[nodeIndex] = node
```

result before update (both are the same):
`Devicesstate true true`

result after update - changing to false (they differ!):
`Devicesstate false true`

I have changed the mutation like that (importing Vue to file):

```
Vue.set(state.nodes, nodeIndex, node)
```

And it works.

Comment: How are you changing the value in the store? There are [certain array modifications](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) that Vue cannot detect.

Comment: thank you for suggestion - works

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the mutation like that (importing Vue to file):

```
Vue.set(state.nodes, nodeIndex, node)
```

And it works.